# infer quarter column from month and month column from quarter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply, purrr

I have a list of data frames with same column names, however some df's have quarter information, and other have month information. Some have both or missing both. all data frames have year info. I am trying to build a condition and derive the missing info, to finally get new columns `QtrYr` and `Date`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- dplyr::tibble(
  m = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 9, NA, NA, 12, NA),
  q = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, NA),
  y = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018 , 2018 , 2018 , 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)
)
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 13 x 3
#>        m     q     y
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1    NA  2016
#>  2     2    NA  2016
#>  3    NA     1  2016
#>  4    NA     2  2017
#>  5    NA     2  2017
#>  6    NA     2  2017
#>  7     7    NA  2018
#>  8    NA     3  2018
#>  9     9     3  2018
#> 10    NA     4  2020
#> 11    NA     4  2020
#> 12    12     4  2020
#> 13    NA    NA  2020

lsdf <- list(df1 = df, df2 = df)
```

---

desired output.

```r
out_df <- dplyr::tibble(
  m = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 9, NA, NA, 12, NA),
  q = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, NA),
  y = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2019, 2020, 2017, 2019, 2020, 2016, 2017, 2019, 2020),
  qy = c("Q1/2016", "Q1/2016", "Q1/2016", "Q2/2017", "Q2/2017", "Q2/2017", "Q3/2018", "Q3/2018", "Q3/2018", "Q4/2020", "Q4/2020", "Q4/2020", NA),
  dy = c("3/1/2016", "3/1/2016", "3/1/2016", "6/1/2017", "6/1/2017", "6/1/2017", "9/1/2018", "9/1/2018", "9/1/2018", "12/1/2020", "12/1/2020", "12/1/2020", NA)
)

print(out_df)
#> # A tibble: 13 x 5
#>        m     q     y qy      dy       
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    
#>  1     1    NA  2016 Q1/2016 3/1/2016 
#>  2     2    NA  2016 Q1/2016 3/1/2016 
#>  3    NA     1  2016 Q1/2016 3/1/2016 
#>  4    NA     2  2017 Q2/2017 6/1/2017 
#>  5    NA     2  2019 Q2/2017 6/1/2017 
#>  6    NA     2  2020 Q2/2017 6/1/2017 
#>  7     7    NA  2017 Q3/2018 9/1/2018 
#>  8    NA     3  2019 Q3/2018 9/1/2018 
#>  9     9     3  2020 Q3/2018 9/1/2018 
#> 10    NA     4  2016 Q4/2020 12/1/2020
#> 11    NA     4  2017 Q4/2020 12/1/2020
#> 12    12     4  2019 Q4/2020 12/1/2020
#> 13    NA    NA  2020 <NA>    <NA>
```

---

I tried to use `case_when`, thought it is fairly straightforward  but looks like either I am not passing it as expected or totally in wrong direction.

```r
lsdf$df1 %>% dplyr::mutate(
  Qrt = dplyr::case_when(
   is.na(m) & is.na(q) ~ NA,
   is.na(m) & !is.na(q) ~ q,
   m != NULL & q == NA ~ paste0("Q",ceiling(as.numeric(m)/3)),
   m != NULL & q != NULL ~ paste0("Q", q)
))
#> Error: `m != NULL & q == NA ~ paste0("Q", ceiling(as.numeric(m)/3))`, `m != NULL & q != NULL ~ paste0("Q", q)` must be length 13 or one, not 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Was thinking I can get a Qtryear column and then run this `zoo` function to get date.

```r
 x <- c("Q1/13", "Q2/14")
as.Date(zoo::as.yearqtr(x, format = "Q%q/%y"))
```

Appreciate any help in solving this.

Comment: I think you need `is.null` and `is.na`

Comment: What is `T` in the case_when

Comment: Just adding TRUE, but could be NA

Comment: it won't work because `case_when` needs to have the same type for all output cases. In the second expression, it is dbl from q and then you are doing `paste`, i.e character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` and `if_else` does type check, so all the condition output needs to be of same type.  Also, not clear why `NULL` should be checked on a vector ie. column as `NULL` would be automatically dropped and it can have an existence in a `list` env

i.e.

```
c(NA, NULL, 1:3)
[1] NA  1  2  3
```

and

```
list(NULL, NULL, 1:3) 
#[[1]]
#NULL

#[[2]]
#NULL

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

In the second case, `NULL` will remain as such

---

Here, if we are doing the checks, use `is.null` along with `is.na`, and make sure the output gets a single type, the `q` column is `numeric` (converted to `character`) while `NA` by default is logical (so use `NA_character_` because the last condition output creates a `character` string with `paste`)

```
library(dplyr)
lsdf$df1 %>% dplyr::mutate(
   Qrt = dplyr::case_when(
    is.na(m) & is.na(q) ~ NA_character_,
    is.na(m) & !is.na(q) ~ as.character(q),
     !is.null(m) & !is.na(q) ~ paste0("Q",ceiling(as.numeric(m)/3)),
      !is.null(m) & !is.null(q) ~ paste0("Q", q)
 ))
```

Also, as it is a `list`, use `map` to loop over the `list`

```
library(purrr)
map(lsdf, ~ .x %>% dplyr::mutate(
   Qrt = dplyr::case_when(
    is.na(m) & is.na(q) ~ NA_character_,
    is.na(m) & !is.na(q) ~ as.character(q),
     !is.null(m) & !is.na(q) ~ paste0("Q",ceiling(as.numeric(m)/3)),
      !is.null(m) & !is.null(q) ~ paste0("Q", q)
 )))
```

#### Update

If we need the 'qy' column as in the updatedd

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
map(lsdf, ~ 
          .x %>%
              mutate(q1 = q) %>%
              fill(q, .direction = "downup") %>%
               mutate(qy = case_when(is.na(m) & is.na(q1) ~ NA_character_, 
                       TRUE ~ str_c("Q", q, "/", y))) %>%
               select(-q1)%>% 
               mutate(dy = floor_date(as.Date(as.yearqtr(qy, "Q%q/%Y"), frac = 1), "month"))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

is this what you were after?

```
lsdf$df1 %>% 
  mutate(Qrt = case_when(
    !is.na(q) ~ q,
    !is.na(m) & is.na(q) ~ ceiling(as.numeric(m)/3),
    is.na(m) & is.na(q) ~ NA_real_
  )) %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(Qrt), NA, paste0(Qrt, "/", y))) %>%
  mutate(x = as.Date(zoo::as.yearqtr(x, format = "%q/%y")))
```

I cleaned up your case_when a little bit. The issue was that you were trying to combine character and numeric outputs. I've changed the `Qrt` variable to be numeric. Hope this helps.